# psychopy microphone recordings cut off

Tags: audio-recording, builder, microphone, psychopy

I am using Psychopy Builder (version 1.78.01, on Windows 7 or Windows XP) to run a language production experiment in which participants see a picture and  have to name it. The picture is supposed to stay on screen for a maximum of 20 seconds, and during this time participants have to produce the response. After the response, they press the space bar and go to the next trial. By pressing the space bar, the program should stop the microphone, based on a code component I've added:

```
   if not continueRoutine and mic.recorder.running:
      mic.recorder.stop()
```

When I run the experiment, it appears to run fine with no error messages, with one .wav file being produced per each trial, as expected. However, some of the audio files (~20%) are truncated shortly after the beginning of the trial (within 1 second) and therefore they are empty or with a truncated response. The problem  starts showing up after about 4 or 5 trials and it's completely random (it is not caused by participants pressing the bar without responding or while they respond, because the RTs for the keypress appear to be accurate in the log file).

I would appreciate any feedback on this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem was posted a while ago, but I was having similar issues and my have found a solution.

I couldn't figure out why my recordings were either truncated, cutting in and out, or completely empty, no matter which setting I changed.

Sounds odd but, as it turns out, it was because I was running the experiment from a flash drive. When I saved everything to my computer and ran it again, the files come out fine.